# Postman Test. Looping through an array of nested objects to find an empty value

Tags: loops, testing, iteration, postman

I would like to ask you for a favour/solution.
I got a test when I have to make sure that each contact contains array 'phone_numbers' and 'email' and got some value (not empty array or value).
I know there is syntax for test such as:

```
pm.test("Check for empty array's values", () => {
pm.expect(jsonData.contacts[1].phone_numbers).to.not.eql([]);
});
```

The problem is that I don’t want to check one by one because sometimes is very large.
I’m pretty sure there an easy solution for that.
I noticed that some contacts contain empty email, phone number or both. e.g. "id": "id": 33333564 which I cannot allow in the future.

Thanks in advance :-)

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 11121211,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": "test1",
      "last_name": "test",
      "company_name": "test",
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1582798926,
      "updated_at": 1582798926,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 60065270,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "+33134567666"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 22222222,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "company_name": null,
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583686067,
      "updated_at": 1583686067,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 22266444,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "+33134567899"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 33333564,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": "Jessica",
      "last_name": "Biel",
      "company_name": "N-Sync",
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583686086,
      "updated_at": 1583686086,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": []
    },
    {
      "id": 45678901,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "company_name": null,
      "information": null,
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583686105,
      "updated_at": 1583686105,
      "emails": [],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 22266444,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "+33134567333"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 56789123,
      "direct_link": "https://example.example",
      "first_name": "Jacky",
      "last_name": "Rowland",
      "company_name": "Test Company1",
      "information": "",
      "is_shared": true,
      "created_at": 1583745888,
      "updated_at": 1608556499,
      "emails": [
        {
          "id": 76594398,
          "label": "Work",
          "value": "mandatory_field@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "phone_numbers": [
        {
          "id": 60650277,
          "label": "Mobile",
          "value": "+33652556777"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "count": 6,
    "total": 241,
    "current_page": 1,
    "per_page": 5,
    "next_page_link": "https://example.example",
    "previous_page_link": null
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the issue with this solution whats the error you get ?

Comment: You mean the solution I mentioned above to.not.eql([])? It works as expected. I just want to run a test which goes through each array within the JSON instead of testing each object array separately

Comment: Did the answer work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = pm.response.json()

 pm.test("Check for empty array's values", () => {
  
    checkEmpty = a.contacts.filter((a) => _.isEqual(a["phone_numbers"], []))
    pm.expect(checkEmpty,JSON.stringify(checkEmpty)).to.be.empty

    

});


pm.test("Check for e5mpty array's values", () => {

    checkEmpty = a.contacts.map((a) => pm.expect(a["phone_numbers"],JSON.stringify(a)).to.be.eq([]))

    

});
```

here we are checking if any element in that contacts array has phone number as empty array, if so then it is returned. And we are expecting that array.filter returns nothing (meaning there shouldn't be any empty phone number)

in second test we are using array.map to check if any function is not empty

**you can use any of the above test functions, the exceptions prints the array content if it fails**

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I define it? I get an error message that is not defined. Sorry to ask you but I'm still learning and sometimes struggle to make the test work..

Comment: a = pm.response.json()

Comment: Thank you , that's what I did for the example shown above and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I struggle with following JSOn:

Comment: a will have full data , and we are iterating through contacts using filter or map

Comment: Again thank you for your help. That way I learn a lot :-)